# URI-encoding - Triangle bracket

Tags: node.js, encoding, express

I am building an app using Node.js
I have a filename with triangle bracket in my app.js file, and I want to send it to the server side (server.js), through a post request.

Here is the code :

app.js

```
filename = encodeURIComponent(filename);
$http.post('/fileInRiskalias/'+  filename)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log("%%%%% success %%%%%")
            }
            )
            .error(function(){
                console.log('error updating new file')
            }
            )
```

Server.js:

```
app.post('/fileInRiskalias/::filename,function(req,res){ 
}
```

The problem is that I always have an post error message, due to the fact that my triangle bracket are "transformed" into "%3C" and "%3D". It doesn't change anything if I encode the filename or not.
Thus the app.post can't work

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

try this on server side:

```
app.post('/fileInRiskalias/:filename,function(req,res){ 
}
```

remove the extra ":" from app.post.

or try this on the http post side:

$http.post('/fileInRiskalias/:'+  filename)

hope this does the trick

Comment: Thx for the answer. the problem is that I need the filename in the server, where I use filename = req.params.filename. If I remove the ":", I won't be able to have access to it anymore.

Comment: check your question you have app.post('/fileInRiskalias/::filename')
remove that extra ":".